# SSAS Tabular projects in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: ssas, visual-studio-2022

I have installed the SSAS extension in Visual Studio 2022, it works well but it allows me to create Multidimensional projects only. "Analysis Services Tabular Project" is missing from the list. Any idea what's going on?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install it from the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022). It looks like there is a [temporary workaround](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022&ssr=false#qna) in the Q&A tab to resolve the issue you are seeing.

> 1. Uninstall AS extension.
> 2. install the AS extension and close the VS2022.
> 3. copy/replace the manifest file(link to download the file is below) in the SSAS folder, a location where your VS22 is installed. For
>    example "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSAS".
> 4. run the following command in cmd at a location where VS2022 is installed. For example "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE" command: "devenv.exe /updateconfiguration"
> 5. open visual studio and it should work fine.
> 6. if it still doesn't, make sure the AS extension is enabled and then execute the 3rd step again after closing VS.
>
> link:
> https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/namangupta_microsoft_com/EdG1BxmX0W5OlLt4CHIZJqYB-8fXSocUi-zK5lqqBLURpg?e=rHCh9F
> By Microsoft 3 hours ago

If you are looking for other extensions in 2022 [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16#install-ssdt-with-visual-studio-2022) has instructions and links.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a old VS 2022 Version. Updating my VS 2022 to 17.3.4 an re-installing SSAS Extension was resolving the issue.

> We now have a permanent fix for the issues. Please go ahead and update
> your VS 2022 version to 17.2.5. You should now be able use Tabular and
> Multidimensional Models.